# Google CodePro dependency graph won't zoom out

Tags: zooming, codepro

I've used Codepro for dependency graphs before and I like it.  It is unsupported and discontinued.  Why?

My (real) question is that I've installed the Indigo 3.7 version (it wouldn't work on Eclipse 4.2 so installed 3.7 just for this purpose) and it does its dependency analysis as expected.  However when I drill in a level the picture is far too big but there seems to be no way zoom out.

I tried a font-size change plugin and that doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to zoom out/in or could suggest plugins that might achieve this?

Comment: I guess noone else could find it either!  SO MY QUESTION THEN IS, why is this discontinued - it is excellent and the only dependency analysis tool I could find that provides an interactive (visual) graph.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you cannot zoom in or zoom out the dependency graph, but you can right click on the  graph, select 'Explore graph' and select 'As Image' to obtain the image of the graph. The image could be zoomed in and out as needed :P.

Comment: Thanks though I'm sure I tried everything obvious.  I'll have a look again next time I fire up Eclipse.